# Are tables 508 compliant when used for calendar display?

Tags: html, fullcalendar, semantics, section508

I cannot seem to find anything here or anywhere else for that matter that answers this question.  I understand tables can be used to display "data" and that there are elements in html5 that represent dates and time for semantic purposes.  I'm trying to implement a calendar in a site that needs to be 508-compliant but also compatible with legacy browsers (IE8+), and came across a great jquery plugin, fullcalendar, but it uses tables to lay out the calendar and so I'm wondering if this is 508 compliant, but can find absolutely zero out there that talks about calendars and 508...

Comment: Hi Levi can you post links for that 508 ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that yes, a table is a proper way to mark up calendar dates.

The semantic use of a table is to hold TABULAR DATA. While I would say that calendar data certainly qualifies, I feel it would be remiss of me not to mention that table based layouts are NOT SEMANTIC, and therefore NOT 508 COMPLIANT.

What I mean by a table based layout is when you have tables nested inside of tables, in an attempt to render a pixel perfect layout with all of your widgets perfectly in their places. If you use that, which hasn't been popular for probably a decade, you might as well send a blind person using an assistive user agent into a virtual maze. Given that your chosen library is written in jQuery, I would like to guess that it's too young to output that kind of awful markup, but I can't be certain. You'll have to use your best judgment, unless you want to share the library on here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the The Office of Accessible Systems & Technology (OAST)(part of Department of Homeland Security) is pretty specific about how it wants to see the HTML for tables and calendars are specifically called out in their test process publication *Section 508 Compliance Test Process for Applications* which can be found at: https://www.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/publications/DHS%20Section%20508%20Compliance%20Test%20Process%20for%20Applications%203.3.pdf.

The section in question is 10.) Web: Data Tables Step 6 and it reads:

> Note: A calendar with days of the week as column headers may be treated as a
>   data table. The visual information must be provided programmatically for each
>   element of the calendar (year, day, month, blackout days, etc.). If all information
>   is provided with the cell data (through TITLE for example), then it may be
>   unnecessary to identify column headers programmatically.

So what it seems to be saying is that as long as you have complete year, month, and other state identifiers in each day cell you don't need to worry about linking the day of the week columns (Sunday, Monday, etc) and the month and year column header (likely spanning entire calendar) with the ID and HEADERS tag (which is required by 508 for other tables with a complex structure like this). Which means calendars as tables are compliant if done correctly.

Answer (score -2):

I would think so, just mark it with a summary and lots of `<th scope="row"` or `"col"`.

Calenders may be considered complex data tables in which you would need `id=` and `headers=` instead.